# Can't add full data in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import a data in mysql workbench which has 8000+ rows but only 100 rows imported

I was trying to add table into the mysql workbench but only 100 rows imported

Comment: What's a data? A csv file perhaps? and are you using import wizard? what does the table look like what import options did you use...

Comment: *only 100 rows imported* This means that 101th row is not correct for current import settings (or at all), and LOAD DATA fails. The rows which are already loaded are not removed for LOAD DATA. See errorlog for the error message and check file to be imported.

Comment: @P.Salmon it is an excel file. yeah I am using import wizard. it is netflix_titles data. i used the utf-8 encoding

Comment: @akina what to check in it i can't find anything